# Is this is a valid estimation for the mass flow required for Hyperloop air-bearings?

Tags: airflow, bearings, compressed-air, air

In Hyperloop air bearings, the air escapes through the rear cross-sectional area of each ski, you know? Yes, there is a pressure differential, but the air comes out of the skis, crashes into the tube and then is accelerated to a certain speed below 760 mph/1,220 kph and escape. The air cannot escape through the front cross-sectional area because of the ski high speed and for the same reason they cannot escape through the lateral areas (well, there will be some minor leaks). That's Couette-Poiseuille flow.

So the mass flow is rho*A*c

Where c is the speed the air is accelerated to, rho is the density, and A the rear cross-sectional area.

What do you think?

Comment: Nobody has yet solved the problem of how to make a viable air bearing this size, especially considering that the air gap on an air bearing is only a few microns and must be accurately polished

Comment: Do you think it would be possible to solve this problem?

Comment: not with air alone.  due to surface roughness

Comment: The tube internal wall can be polished as much as you want. Air bearings are a cheap solution for Hyperloop.

Comment: to what coplanarity? um/km

Comment: I don't know. I would need 500 um/km. The tube is 3.3 m wide. Is that possible?

Comment: not with earth movements

Comment: Well, they would be dampeners.

Comment: But in project I used the hypothesis that the tolerance was small enough (500 um/km would be OK) so that the air bearings could work perfectly. The problem is the mass flow. 0.2 kg/s is enough to lift 15 tons?